# Registration form SQL syntax error

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a very simple registration form. But when I get an error that says that I have an error in my SQL syntax.

But it says that I have the problem on the line where I wrote:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

I guess it's because it can not execute the SQL question?

My code:

```
<?php
require 'anslut.php';

$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

$output = "";
if (isset($submit)) {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);


if ($name == "" || $username == "" || $password == "") {
    $output .= "All fields must be entered";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, namn) VALUES :username, :password, :name";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $output .= "Registration successful";
    $output .= "<a href='index.php'>Follow the link to log in</a>";
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register here</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Your name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Username:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="submit">Register</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php print($output); ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I think INSERT INTO users(username, password, namn)  namn shoud be name

Comment: You misspelled namn in your query

Comment: `VALUES :username, :password, :name` should probably be `VALUES (:username, :password, :name)`. "namn" is swedish for "name", so _may_ be the correct field name in the database.

Comment: Its just a typo, Close it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO users(username, password, namn) VALUES :username, :password, :name
                          spelling? -----^         ^------ parentheses ------^
```

The spelling one is mostly a guess, but at the very least the parentheses are a good idea.  So maybe you meant this?:

```
INSERT INTO users(username, password, name) VALUES (:username, :password, :name)
```

Also, as a side note, *never* store user passwords *in plain text*.  This is very irresponsible handling of user data.  PHP has a lot of [built-in functionality](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to assist in properly obscuring user passwords behind a one-way hash.  (As well as [a compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for older PHP versions.)

Comment: Sorry about the spelling, i'm swedish and "namn" is swedish for name.. I accidentally put "namn" in my database table, opsie

Comment: @Addeuz: That's why it was mostly a guess.  It seemed like a reasonable spelling depending on the language, and non-English languages often mix with English in software systems just because the tooling can be very English-centric.  Glad I could help with the SQL syntax though!

Answer (score 6):

The syntax error is because you need parenthesis around your values:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (Value1, Value2)
```

Comment: please remove comma (Column1, Column2), :)

Answer (score 0):

enclose the variables in single quotes because these are string and strings cannot be directly inserted in database. e.g

```
INSERT INTO talbe_name (col1,col2) VALUES ('string1','string2');
```

also draw `{}` around variables inside the string in php code e.g

```
 <?php
     $str = "Value={$variable}";
  ?>
```

Comment: The `{}` is not necessary for scalar variables in a double quoted string. Use this when using arrays and object properties.

Comment: What do PHP variables have to do with the SQL query in the question?  Are you actually suggesting that the OP *not use prepared statements* and instead use *string interpolation of user input values*?

Comment: I was telling you about the php syntax, when you are generating the sql query in php then use {}.

Comment: @ZahidIqbal: What you're doing is suggesting that the OP replace a perfectly good prepared statement with your SQL injection vulnerability.  Not only does your code not answer the question, it recommends terrible practices.